# is this set finite or infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the set
$\{2k \mid k \in  \mathbb{N}\} \cap \{3k \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$
finite or infinite? Justify your answer.

I understand $\cap$ means the intersection of the two sets so it will be all the elements that are in the first set and the second set and elements that are only in one set will be disregarded.

However as it is asking $2k$ is in the set such that $k$ is a element of the natural numbers and $3k$ is a element of the set such that $k$ is a element of the set of integers the set is finite as if a number from the first set such as $6$ which is $2\cdot 3$ and then a number in the second set would be $6$ which is $3\cdot 2$ will be in the intersection set. This will mean that as you go through the natural numbers and integers the set will become finite..

Am i right with this explanation, if so is there a better way of explaining it and if not can you please explain how to work it out?

Comment: Try to write the first elements of these two sets. (Like, from 0 to 30, which numbers are elements of the first one? of the second one?) You will probably get a better idea then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\{2k \mid k \in  \mathbb{N}\} \cap \{3k \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}=\{6k \mid k \in  \mathbb{N}\}$

Answer (score 4):

Consider that the elements of the first set are all the natural numbers divisible by 2 and elements of the second set are all the integral numbers divisible by 3 (though you might as well consider just the natural numbers since the first set already restricts you). Thus the intersection must be the natural numbers divisible by what? And then consider how many of those there are.